# Make group for radio button

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have 4 radiobutton. 
Now, I want to group it to 2group.

```
 QRadioButton *radio1 = new QRadioButton(tr("R&adio button 1"));
 QRadioButton *radio2 = new QRadioButton(tr("R&adio button 2"));
 QRadioButton *radio3 = new QRadioButton(tr("R&adio button 3"));
 QRadioButton *radio4 = new QRadioButton(tr("R&adio button 4"));
```

What will I do . 
Using QT.Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

use QButtonGroup http://www.ostools.net/uploads/apidocs/qt/qbuttongroup.html and define each radiobutton with checkid ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `QGroupBox` for grouping multiple `radiobuttons` together please try it

Use two differnt `QGroupBox` for grouping them into different sets and then you can use this `QGroupBox` in the layout